# Add Line break in SVG Title tag

Tags: html, css, svg

is it possible to have multiple lines inside an SVG title tag?

```
<title> Name: Jon \n Address: NY </title>
```

I tried to add \n and apply some CSS to break the title text but it's not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065896/d3-multi-line-tooltip-for-svg-element

Answer (score 4):

Actual newlines work, or at least they do in Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

```html
<svg>
  <rect width="300" height="150" fill="lime">
    <title> Name: Jon 
    Address: NY </title>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Or use an entity: `<title> Name: Jon&#10;Address: NY </title>`